# JDBC-ODBC not found exception

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc

I'm trying to access a Microsoft Excel file via Java by using the sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver. However, I keep getting ClassNotFoundException.

```
 try
 {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, ex.toString());
 }
```

Any ideas ?
Does this driver come with the standard Java installation or do I have to download this driver from the Internet ? If so, where do I find this driver ?

Comment: What JRE do you use? This class may be missing in non Oracle JREs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is that this works in Windows but doesn't seem to work in Ubuntu ( business / copyright reasons ??? Who knows )

Comment: You're probably just using a JRE that doesn't have this class, since this is one of the closed-source classes (IIRC you need to jump through some hoops in Ubuntu to install the Oracle JRE/JDK). It might be better to download a JDBC driver for Excel like [xlsql](http://xlsql.sourceforge.net/) to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use the `.newInstance()` method? Remove it and it should work.

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
```

Comment: Hi, actually it doesn't work even when I don't use the .newInstance() method. :-)